# Derivative function at the point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anyone help me out with the question below?

Let $ f: \Bbb{R}→ \Bbb{R} $ be a function such that $ \vert f (x) −f (p)\vert\le \vert x-p \vert^{3\over 2}$ , for all $ x, p \in \Bbb{R}$. Show
that $ f$ is derivable, calculating its derivative at each point.

Comment: I don't think it is differentiable everywhere.It is differentiable almost everywhere.check following theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem

Comment: Consider $ f(x)= \vert x\vert$. But $ f$ is not differentiable at $ x=0$

Answer (score 1):

From $|f(x)-f(p)|\le |x-p|^{3\over 2}$, you may write $$\left|{f(x)-f(p)\over x-p}\right|\le\sqrt{|x-p|}$$which, by letting $x\to p$, yields $$|f'(p)|\le \epsilon\to f'(p)=0$$for every $\epsilon>0$ and $p\in\Bbb R$. Hence the function must be constant every where .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm so sorry, but I made a mistake while typing the question here, I am sorry again. Could you reconsider your answer with the new information? Thanks a lot. All the (x-p) is inside of the sqrt, and it's elevated to the cube. Thank you!

Comment: It is OK. I revised the answer. Hope it help now.

Comment: God bless you, Mostafa! Let me see if I understand correctly: f is derivable, and its results is constant at every point. Is that right?

Comment: The result of derivative is zero everywhere and the only function with such a property is the constant function.

Comment: Got it, thanks a million!!!

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck!